# Get Notification Body on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

I would like to get the body-content/text of a notification and save that text in a variable after I clicked on an action button.

For example, I get a notification and there are 2 action buttons. If I click on the first of them it will save the Body-Content of the notification in a variable named "Content". If I click on the 2nd one it will get the notification title and save that in a variable named "Title".

The Body and Title Content is variable.

**Practical Example:**

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if response.actionIdentifier == "Yes" {
        //var Content = the content of the Notification
    } else {
        //var Title = the Title of the Notification
    }

    scheduleNotification()
    completionHandler()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save to user defaults

set data:

```swift
 UserDefaults.standard.set("Title from notification", forKey: "TITLE")
```

Get data:

```swift
let titleValue = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"TITLE") as? String
```

If you want to reset the value after using it just keep `nil` value for same key.